# Why is _dl_fixup called before dynamic linker start?

Tags: c, linker, glibc

I'm trying to understand how glibc dynamic linker works. I know that _dl_fixup is called in _dl_runtime_resolve, and solves the relocation problems. So I thought it's called only after linker starts and has loaded some libraries. But when I do some print work in it, I find the function is called even before _dl_start. It's confusing: why it was called? What work it has done?

I did some print work, the function is working on symbols like strncpy, fopen, fread64 and so on, but the object name(l->l_name) seems to be null.

[image: I add print sentences in _dl_start and _dl_fixup]

[image: I make glibc and test the ld.so, I found "_dl_fixup" appears before and after "_dl_start"]

I use gdb to debug the linker, and I think gdb itself used _dl_fixup to complete some tasks. If I didn't use gdb, the _dl_fixup will be called only after _dl_start.

Answer (score 0):

> So I thought it's called only after linker starts and has loaded some libraries

That is correct.

> I find the function is called even before _dl_start

This is not correct: `_dl_fixup` is called only after `_dl_start`.

Unfortunately you didn't provide any details on how you've came to the incorrect conclusion, so it's impossible to tell you where you made a mistake, but you did make (at least one) mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I link two pics about the details, can you point out my mistake?:)